# Why would $1^{-\infty}$ not be 1?

Tags: limits, power-series, infinite-product, mathematica

It would seem to me that $1^{-∞}=\lim_\limits{x→∞}1^{-x}=\lim_\limits{x→∞}\frac1{1^x}=\frac11=1$ no matter how we approach it. However, [Wolfram Alpha answers](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%5E-%E2%88%9E) with a mysteriously unqualified “$\text{(undefined)}$”. Similarly, [JavaScript also thinks](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/OT@vOD8nVS8nP13DUEtL1zMvLTMvs6RS8/9/AA) that the result isn't a number. On the other hand, the very mathematically inclined [APL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(programming_language)) languages [NARS2000](https://aplwiki.com/NARS2000) and [J](https://aplwiki.com/J) both [have it give](https://tio.run/##y/r/PzU5I1/BMC4@/v9/AA) $1$.

What reasons are there to reject $1^{-∞}=1$?

Comment: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{-n} = \frac{1}{e}\neq 1$

Comment: $1^x=e^{x\log(1)}$ and $\log(1)=i2k\pi$ for integer $k$.

Comment: @jmoravitz The OP is asking about $1^x$ as $x\to -\infty$.

Comment: $1^\infty$ is not defined and can, in principle, be any positive number or not convergent at all. For example $\lim_{n\to\infty}( 1+1/n)^n=e$.

Comment: @MarkViola Beginners will often "plug in infinity" into these expressions and would have after "plugging in infinity" into $(1+\frac{1}{n})^{-n}$ have called this $(1+\frac{1}{\infty})^{-\infty}$ which they may have then "simplified" to $1^{-\infty}$ incorrectly.  There is not sufficient evidence for me in the question to assume that this is not the case here.  The OP writes $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}1^{-x}$ only *after* having introduced the expression $1^{-\infty}$.

Comment: The end result is that the expression $1^{-\infty}$ is meaningless.  The only acceptable related expressions all very explicitly the expression in terms of a limit and make it clear how the base and how the exponent change (*or not*) as the limiting variable advances.

Comment: @JMoravitz It's plausible that $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}1^x$ is interpreted as $\lim_{x\to\pm \infty }e^{x\log(1)}$, where $\log(z)$ is the complex logarithm.  And only on a branch for which $\log(1)=0$ does the limit exist.  Otherwise for $k\ne0$, $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}e^{i2\pi k x}$ fails to exist. ;-(

Comment: I am not concerned with the definition of $\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}1^x$ in this problem.  I am only concerned with the definition of $1^{-\infty}$ and deny the notion that the two should be automatically assumed to be equivalent here.

Comment: @JMoravitz Sorry but I don't agree for the closure as a duplicate. I agree of course that the OP are strictly related but here the asker is asking for a different thing that is the different answers obtained from wolfram and others math tools. Indeed I was also expecting for a specific answer to that issue by some expert in this field. For that reason I'm going to vote to reopen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since for any $x$ we have $1^x=1$ as you noticed

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty} 1^x  =\lim_{x\to -\infty} 1=1$$

and you are completely right on that, but as $f(x)\to 1$

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty} \left(f(x)\right)^x  $$

is an indeterminate form, that is we can obtain any result depending on the nature of $f(x)$.

Probably by this input wolfram refer symbolically to this latter case.

Comment: Very nice answer.

Comment: Is there a reason why the 1 in $\lim_{x\to -\infty} 1^x$ is interpreted as constant 1 unlike in $1^{-\infty}$?

Comment: The fact is that for any $x$ we have $1^x=1$ therefore we are taking the limit for the constant $1$.

Comment: @Bubbler More in detail, refer to the defintion of limit and consider that in this case $\left|1^x-1\right|=0$.

Comment: Umm... To clarify a bit, I was asking about the possibility of interpreting $\lim_{x\to -\infty} 1^x$ as $\lim_{x\to -\infty} (\lim_{y\to 1} (y^x))$. Though they would be equal here anyway since the inner limit does evaluate to 1 for any fixed value of $x$.

Comment: @Bubbler Indeed for the iterated limit $$\lim_{x\to -\infty} (\lim_{y\to 1} (y^x))=\lim_{x\to -\infty} 1^x=\lim_{x\to -\infty} 1=1$$ We can also give to $1^{-\infty}$ a meaning but we need to clarify that and define it. This is probably why different math tools give different answers.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{array}{}
\left( 1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^{-n} \to e^{-1} \\
\left( 1+\frac{1}{n^2} \right)^{-n} \to 1 \\
\left( 1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^{-n^2} \to 0 
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 0):

The value $1^\infty$ is indeterminate. It can be interpreted as $$\lim_{x\to \infty} 1^x=1,$$ as $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n =e,$$ among others. This ambiguity makes it indeterminate. BPRP has some good videos delving deeper into this concept.